# How to get the Identity values in SQL BULK COPY?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I have to get the IDENTITY values from a table after SQLBULKCOPY to the same table. The volume of data could be thousands of records.

Can someone help me out on this ?

Comment: just get the IDENTITY  the same way you would if you inserted 1 record... the number of records is irrelevant?

Comment: select them after they are inserted, you would need to include a bulk inserted identifier... so add column batchId or something and then re-select all records with the same batchid.

Comment: just out of interest how many records are we talking about. (Ball park)

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Bulk Operations](http://bulk-operations.net/)

In short, this project overcomes SqlBulkCopy limitations by adding MUST-HAVE features like outputting inserted identity value.

Under the hood, it uses SqlBulkCopy and a similar method as @Mr Moose answer.

```
var bulk = new BulkOperation(connection)

// Output Identity Value
bulk.ColumnMappings.Add("CustomerID", ColumnMappingDirectionType.Output);

// Map Column
bulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Code");
bulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Name");
bulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Email");

bulk.BulkInsert(dt);
```

**EDIT:** Answer comment

> can I simply get a IList or simply , I see its saved back in the customers table, but there is no variable where I can get a hold of it, can you please help with that. So, I an insert in Orders.CustomerID table

It depends, you can keep a reference to the Customer DataRow named `CustomerRef` in the Order `DataTable`.

So once you merged your customer, you are able to populate easily a column `CustomerID` from the column `CustomerRef` in your Order DataTable.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to say: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hw5rf3

Comment: Hi how can I add/map the `bulk.ColumnMappings.Add("CustomerID", ColumnMappingDirectionType.Output);` to a different table like  for e.g. a `customerOrder table`

Comment: You cannot map it to a different table. You can return it however and use the value for the next bulk operations. Here is a Fiddle that shows how to return the value: https://dotnetfiddle.net/g5pSS1

Comment: wow, this is much simpler easier lib to use. I got stuck, _was not able to get the output ids_  https://dotnetfiddle.net/yMfhPD , how can I get the output id's cached/list? can I simply get a IList<int> or simply , I see its saved back in the customers table, but there is no variable where I can get a hold of it, can you please help with that. So, I an insert in `Orders.CustomerID` table

Answer (score 0):

I've used a solution similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2945628/685760) from Marc Gravell in that it is useful to first import into a temp table.

I've also used the `MERGE` and `OUTPUT` as described by Jamie Thomson [on this post](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2010/01/06/merge-and-output-the-swiss-army-knife-of-t-sql.aspx) to track data I have inserted into my temp table to match it with the id generated by the IDENTITY column of the table I want to insert into.

This is particularly useful when you need to use that ID as a foreign key reference to other tables you are populating.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE #temp 
(
    DataRow varchar(max)
)
BULK INSERT #Temp FROM 'C:\tt.txt'  

ALTER TABLE #temp
ADD id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL

SELECT * FROM #temp
```

Answer (score -3):

```
-- dummy schema
 CREATE TABLE TMP (data varchar(max))
 CREATE TABLE [Table1] (id int not null identity(1,1), data varchar(max))
 CREATE TABLE [Table2] (id int not null identity(1,1), id1 int not null, data varchar(max))

 -- imagine this is the SqlBulkCopy
 INSERT TMP VALUES('abc')
 INSERT TMP VALUES('def')
 INSERT TMP VALUES('ghi')

 -- now push into the real tables
 INSERT [Table1]
 OUTPUT INSERTED.id, INSERTED.data INTO [Table2](id1,data)
 SELECT data FROM TMP
```

Comment: @Ann88, that is directly copied from Marc Gravell's answer I linked in my answer. Please ensure you note the source of your answer if you are going to copy it.